# How can I select a boolean literal in HQL?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, nhibernate-4

I can select int and string literals in HQL like so:

`select 'a string' as StringLiteral, 1 as IntLiteral from Eg.MyClass`

but I haven't found a way to select a boolean literal. I've tried `select true ...`, and `select new bool true ...` but those cause HQL syntax exceptions.

Is there a way to select a boolean literal in HQL?

I have found a workaround (`select case when (1=1) then true...`), but that seems inefficient...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually no real booleans in SQL (as in `Select 1=1`), except of in conditions. HQL turns "true" and "false" into 0 and 1 I think (something you can configure somewhere), but I guess it is still an integer.

Simplest things you can most probably do is convert the integer to a boolean in memory after the query.

Comment: The cast can be done in HQL. See my [answer](/a/35948398/1178314).

Answer (score 2):

```sql
select cast(1 as bool) as bitLiteral from Eg.MyClass
```

NHibernate usually supports the same features as Hibernate. This was elaborated from this [answer](/a/4793868/1178314). I have tested it with NHibernate.

NHibernate maps SQL [`bit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx) type to .Net `bool` type.

The cast is required in plain SQL too, as SQL (at least SQL Server Transact-SQL) [lacks bit literals](/q/1172795/1178314).

Comment: Wow, this is really great. Didn't know this. The cool thing about it is that you can use the (N)Hibernate type after `as`, not some kind of DBMS specific type. You still cannot cast a boolean expression to bool (as in `1=1`, only when using a `CASE` expression), something I often miss.